# best way to have more than one function for react onClick events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react button component that receives 1 function as prop to be executed on the `onClick` event

```
<Button onClick={() => console.log('hello')}>
```

this passes as

```
<button onClick={onClick}>
  Say hello
</button>
```

A new requirement has come, and we need to make a ping to our server to see how many users actually click on the button, but not every button will share this behaviour, what would be a clean way to add a new property and if it is present, execute both functions on click

```
<Button
    onClick={() => console.log('hello')}
    track=true
/>
```

```
<button
  onClick={() =>{
     if track trackClick()
     onClick()
  }}>
  Say hello
</button>
```

Comment: What you have seems like a reasonable start.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: This sounds pretty basic. What have you tried that didn't work? It comes across pretty bad as-is, like you're asking for free code

Comment: I updated the code to add what i have in mind

Comment: @azibi and did it not work?

Comment: Yes, just wondering if there's a better approach

Comment: Please see the [help/on-topic]. Opinion based questions are not on topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift everything into the parent component. Have a state that logs the counts of the buttons, and have your `handleClick` function call the first function and then, depending on the `track` information, update the count. Button1, in this example, will call `doThing` first and then update the count; Button2 will only call the function, and not update the count.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => console.log(count), [count]);

  function doThing() {
    console.log('Thing');
  }

  function handleClick(e) {
    const { track } = e.target.dataset;
    doThing();
    if (track === 'true') setCount(count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        handleClick={handleClick}
        text="Button1"
        track={true}
      />
      <Button
        handleClick={handleClick}
        text="Button2"
        track={false}
      />
    </div>
  );

}

function Button({ handleClick, text, track }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleClick}
      data-track={track}
    >{text}
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```